# Transposing a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I created this table so that it is a collection of 5 different functions that I need. It outputs the values that I want, however, I cannot figure out how to get the orientation right. I would like to flip the chart so that the pressures, the labels and the corresponding values are aligned vertically instead of horizontally. Is this possible? Here is the code (It's a bit ugly, I'm just learning *Mathematica*):

```
β = 10^-1 ; (*Ratio of pipe diameter to orifice diameter*)
Cd = 0.61;   (*Discharge coefficient*)
orificeDiameter = Quantity[1, "mm"];
targetDiameter = Quantity[3, "mm"];
valveTime = 
 Quantity[150, "microseconds"];  (* average valve time from a 50-75\[Mu]s input \
electrical pulse using the dual piezo actuator design (design 2) from \
Proctor et al.*)
P = Quantity[100, "psi"];  (*high pressure assumptions*)
T = Quantity[300, "K"]; (*room temp assumption*)
kb = Quantity[1, "BoltzmannConstant"];
mh = Quantity[3.35 * 10^(-27), "kg"]; (*mass of H2*)
n = UnitConvert[(P/(kb*T)), "m^-3"]; (*1/volume of 1 gas particle*)
ρ  = mh*n;
A = UnitConvert[π*(orificeDiameter/2)^2, "m^2"];
vThermal = UnitConvert[Sqrt[(kb*T)/mh], "m/s"];
Print["***OUTPUT***"]
Print["Volume Flux:"]
Q  = Cd*A*Sqrt[(2*P)/(ρ*(1 - β^4))];
(*Q = Quantity[10^-7, "cm^3 s^-1 atm^-1"]*UnitConvert[P, "atm"]*)
Q = UnitConvert[Q, "m^3 * s^-1"]
Print["Number Flux:"]
NumFlux = n*Q
Print["Target Density:"]
ColumnDensity = 
 UnitConvert[ NumFlux/(π*(targetDiameter/2)^2*vThermal), "cm^-3"]

Print["Target Length (cylinder approx)"]
PuffLength = vThermal*valveTime

Print["Total # Particles Vented to LAPD"]
TotalParticlesAdded = NumFlux*valveTime

qList = Table[Q*Sqrt[i] // N, {i, 7}];
nfList = Table[n*Q*Sqrt[i] // N, {i, 7}];
tdList = Table[ColumnDensity*Sqrt[i] // N, {i, 7}];
tlList = Table[PuffLength*Sqrt[i] // N, {i, 7}];
tpList = Table[TotalParticlesAdded*Sqrt[i] // N, {i, 7}];

TableForm[{qList, nfList, tdList, tlList, tpList}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"Volume Flux", "Number Flux", "Target Density", 
    "Target Length (cylinder approx)", 
    "Total # Particles Vented to LAPD"}, {"100Psi", "200Psi", 
    "300Psi", "400Psi", "500Psi", "600Psi", "700Psi"}}]
```

Here is an image of what it does now so you can see what I have in mind. I want to flip the image so the pressure increments are labeled along the side and the relevant values go down instead of across.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)?

Comment: Simply : `TableForm[Transpose @ {qList, nfList, tdList, tlList, tpList}, 
 TableHeadings -> 
  Reverse @{{"Volume Flux", "Number Flux", "Target Density", 
     "Target Length (cylinder approx)", 
     "Total # Particles Vented to LAPD"}, {"100Psi", "200Psi", 
     "300Psi", "400Psi", "500Psi", "600Psi", "700Psi"}}]`

Comment: Thank you! Well now I feel stupid, I was trying different variations of Transpose[TableForm[...]] for so long and it just wasn't working. The page on the Wolfram library for Transpose wasn't making it very clear. Thanks again!